# Use Yang's inequality to prove $ab\leq e^{a-1}+b\ln b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, integral-inequality

> Use Yang's inequality to prove: if $a,b\geq 1$, then $ab\leq e^{a-1}+b\ln b$.
>
> Here is the definition of Yang's inequality the exercise gives:
>
> Let $f\in C^1[0,+\infty)$ be strictly monotone increasing, $f(0)=0$, $a,b>0$, then we have
>   $$
> ab\leq\int_0^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^b g(y)\mathrm{d}y
> $$
>   where $g(y)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)$.

I tried it by setting $f(x)=e^{x-1}-e^{-1}$(to satisfy $f(0)=0$ and the term $e^{a-1}$). Then I get $$g(y)=\ln(e^{-1}+y) +1$$  $$\int_0^x f(x)=e^{x-1}-e^{-1}x-e^{-1}$$ and $$\int_0^y g(y)=(e^{-1}+x)\ln(e^{-1}+x)+e^{-1}.$$
Substitute the Yang's inequality I get

$$
ab\leq e^{a-1}-e^{-1}a+(e^{-1}+b)\ln(e^{-1}+b).
$$
This cannot solve my question. Is there anything wrong in my derivation or I just choose the wrong function $f(x)$?

I even tried the function $e^x-1$ for $a$ and $eb$ still  not work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with L. Yang, but it is a good bet that one integral endpoint is $a$ but the other is $b,$ giving $$
ab\leq\int_0^a f(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_0^b g(y)\mathrm{d}y
$$  rather than what you have

Comment: @WillJagy  I've corrected it, thank you.

Comment: So, for example, when $f(x) = x,$ we are told $$ ab \leq \frac{a^2}{2} + \frac{b^2}{2} $$ for positive $a,b,$ which is true. You have a source for the inequality? I cannot find one.

Comment: @WillJagy Young's inequality for products.

Comment: @WillJagy I've corrected the inequality you pointed. And here is the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products

Comment: @Ahmad good https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality_for_products#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions

Comment: Given that $f(x)=e^{x-1}$ so $f^{-1}(x) = \ln(x)+ 1$ and we get that $a b \leq e^{x-1} -\frac{1}{e} +b \ln b \leq e^{x-1} +b \ln b$, but $f(0)=\frac{1}{e} \approx 0.367$, so my guess is that the inequality also holds when $f(0) \geq 0$, not sure.

Comment: @Ahmad It seems to be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[One Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality_for_products#Standard_version_for_increasing_functions)

Functions $$ f(x) = e^x - 1,  $$ with antiderivative
$$ e^x - x - 1  $$ that also vanishes at the origin, to fit the given integral.  Then
$$ g(y) = \log (1+y), $$ antiderivative
$$  (1 + y)\log (1 + y) - y, $$ vanishes at zero.

Apply inequality for

$$  a-1, b-1 $$
which are positive, as required.

Comment: Fast learning, +1

Comment: @Ahmad thanks..